# Response from controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a controller class that someone at work wrote that contains a method that looks like this.

(obviously it's not the full code, just the part I find confusing). It's part of a ASP.Net Core project.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(newZipPath))
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
}

return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip");
```

Now I'm not that good at C# but it feels like that "result" variable is not going to be sent anywhere or used? Am I correct or does ASP.Net Core have some magic way of sending this result as well as the one in the return statement.

Comment: Yes as per code result has nothing to with return, and other part of the code is good on its own, as i have used such code in my project.

Comment: I strongly recommend checking [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0). As you can see, [`return File(stream, contentType);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-io-stream-system-string)) already returns a status of 200 (OK) by default.

Comment: Perhaps you really just want [`return File(newZipPath, "application/zip");`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-string-system-string))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. There doesn't appear to be any point in the `result` variable, ASP.Net MVC (both Framework and Core versions) will generate an appropriate FileResult from `File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip");`.

You could go one step further and really reduce this code even more:

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(newZipPath))
{
    return File(stream, "application/zip");
}
```

No need to create a second MemoryStream ar convert it to a byte array.